# NullPointerException, killed my program

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I'm trying to create my little box that shows the color when selected from the combo box. But I keep getting this error of NullPointerException when I try to run the program. I don't see what is wrong with it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ThreeColorsFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

    private JComboBox box;
    private JLabel picture;

    private static String[] filename = { "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
    private Icon[] pics = { new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0])),
                    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[1])),
                    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[2])) };

    public ThreeColorsFrame()
    {
        super("ThreeColorsFrame");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        box = new JComboBox(filename);

        box.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
        {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
            }
        });

        add(box);
        picture = new JLabel(pics[0]);
        add(picture);

    }

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ThreeColorsFrame.<init>(ThreeColorsFrame.java:33)
    at ThreeColorsViewer.main(ThreeColorsViewer.java:36)
```

Comment: Post your error stack trace

Comment: *"NullPointerException when I try to run the program"*  Copy/paste the stack trace as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15998813/edit).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you haven't initialized `picture`. You have

```
private JLabel picture;
```

But this never gets set before:

```
 picture.setIcon(...);
```

is called in the constructor, albeit within a condition.

You need to initialize it, eg

```
picture = new JLabel(...); // whatever
```

Comment: I did that towards the bottom.    
     {picture = new JLabel(pics[0]);}

Comment: You need to do move your code around so this situation where picture is null can't occur when invoking a method on it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `picture` object before you have initialized it.

**USE**

```
picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
```

**INITIALIZATION**

```
picture = new JLabel(pics[0]);
```

Move the initialization statement above the listener.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to initialize `picture` as soon as you declare it.

So instead of using `private JLabel picture;` try to use:

`private JLabel picture = new JLabel(pics[0]);`